# WEBDRIVERIO / CUCUMBER : Function timeout , Ensure Promise resolves within 10000 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

Hi I am currently working on an application that includes series of page navigation for an user to complete info. In order to navigate to a certain part of the page, I tried creating a generic step definition as a "background" step to cover all the precondition steps.

```
Background:
           Given I am the Page10 of the application

Given(/^I am on a specific Page$/,function(){
//Implementation of Page 1 to Page 9 
})
```

Every such page has its seperate step definition and page object functions .. And in this specfic page10 , I tried including all the page object functions. But unfortunately I am getting "function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 100000 milliseconds"

Is there a way to fix this?

```
timeout: 300000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
```

As above, I set my wdio.conf.js timeout parameter as 20000 to 300000 , but have to keep increasing it more and more as the page navigation gets wider. Also, I feel this is not a right approach. As the light weight steps would then wait for a longer period to throw error messages

Please let me know the best way to fix this?

PS: As I reckon this issue self explanatory and hence no code added. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: don't use explicit timeouts. Change it to either FluentWait or WebDriver Wait on some locator on that page.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek_Mishra . Will try it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a specific timeout for your background step:

```
Given('your step', { timeout: 70000 }, function () {
    // your code here
})
```

Please let me know if that's not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: This is a new approach to me. So  instead of considering the default time-outs I can pass it in the step definition as well? A decent workaround to the one I have. Will try it out first and update.

Comment: Exactly !
[Here is the official documentation for this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/timeouts.md)